# (Ubuntu) Error: IPython Qtconsole not launching

Tags: python, qt4, ubuntu-12.04, ipython

When I try launch Ipython qtconsole from terminal, I get the following error:

```
python: /build/buildd/sip4-4.13.2/siplib/siplib.c:7915: sip_api_can_convert_to_type: Assertion `(((td)->td_flags & 0x0007) == 0x0000) || (((td)->td_flags & 0x0007) == 0x0002)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This could be due to the qt broken packages, but I don't know which ones! I could really use your opinions in solving this issue :). Thanks!

I use python 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I have that problem.  when i install python v.3 To launch ipython:  i type in console ipython3.
Try reinstall ipython :-)
    sudo apt-get remove ipython
    sudo apt-get purge ipython
    sudo apt-get install ipython

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did that but in vain :(, I get the same error :(